# I just want to use a C++11 lib in Android 4.4

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk, antlr

I want to embed Antlr4.8 C++ runtime lib in our App which supports Android 4.4.

I have checked the official Google Doc about NDK, but still **don't know the relationship between NDK version and Android System version and C++ version.**

So can anyone give me some tip or "more detail" Doc about embed C++11 lib in Android App?
Thanks.

By the way, i am an iOS developer so this is difficult for me and i still try hard to learn Android NDK development.

Comment: _"On Android, the libc++ used by the NDK is not part of the OS. This gives NDK users access to the latest libc++ features and bug fixes even when targeting old versions of Android. The trade-off is that if you use libc++_shared.so, you must include it in your APK. If you're building your application with Gradle this is handled automatically."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [release notes](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/introducing-ndk-r21-our-first-long-term.html) of the current Android NDK v21, the toolchain uses Clang release r365631 (the master branch as of 10 July 2019), which corresponds to Clang 9.0.6.

That means that C++ is [supported](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) all the way up to C++17, and even some parts of C++20.

So C++11 is no problem at all.

---

Note: to use the latest C++17 features, you might have to link with the latest libc++ statically (`-static-libstdc++`), as explained [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/refs/heads/ndk-release-r21/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md#libc). For C++11 this most likely won't be needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It gives a clear path for me and i will try it.